# Is having async producer-consumer helps to not steal a thread for duration of whole program?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, producer-consumer

The code below receives messages from tcp and passes them to the appropriate message handler. Depending on the message type, a message handler may take many minutes or several seconds to process it.

I chose the design of having a separate handler for each message type. But, now I'm thinking:

1. Even though I have async producer-consumer (`await _messages.Reader.WaitToReadAsync()`), I still have `Task.Run` with a loop for each message handler, meaning it will hold a whole thread from thread pool for duration of the whole program, right? So, If I have 3 message handlers, I'm holding 3 threads from thread pool, right?
2. Is there any benefit at all of using async producer-consumer in the way the code is currently implemented? Again, since each message handler starts `Task.Run` for duration of the whole program I think there is no benefit and I could use in general just a synchronous collection like `BlockingCollection`, right?
3. What is the better way to do this? Should I just have one message handler with single `Task.Run` that have a loop and checks for new messages and it will spawn other `Task.Run`s for new massage? But, I need a way to wait for the previous Task to complete and not block checking on  new messages. Maybe I should have some cancelable-execution task so I could cancel the prevoius one and start a new one for same message type?

**CODE**

```
    public class Distributor
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<string, MessageHandler> _messageHandlers;

        public void StartReceive()
        {
              // tcpClient PSEUDO CODE
              while (_tcpClient.NewMessageAvailable)
              { 
                  var data = _tcpClient.GetNewMessage();

                  _messageHandlers[data.MsgType].Add(data.Data);
              }
        }
 
        private void RegisterMessageHandlers()
        {
            _messageHandlers["msgType1"] = new MyMessageHandler1(...);
            _messageHandlers["msgType2"] = new MyMessageHandler2(...);
            _messageHandlers["msgType3"] = new MyMessageHandler3(...);
           ...
        }
    }

    public abstract class MessageHandler
    {
        private readonly Channel<string> _messages;

        public MessageHandler()
        {
           _messages = Channel.CreateBounded<int>(new BoundedChannelOptions(1)
           {
              SingleReader = true,
              SingleWriter = true,
              FullMode = BoundedChannelFullMode.DropOldest,
           });
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            _task = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                try
                {                        
                     while (await _messages.Reader.WaitToReadAsync())
                     {
                         try
                         {
                             _messages.Reader.TryRead(out var msg);
                             await Task.Run(async () => await HandleAsync(msg));
                         }
                         catch (Exception ex)
                         {
                         }
                     }
                }
                catch { } // OperationCanceledException
            }
        }
    
        public void Add(string msg)
        {
            _messages.Writer.TryWrite(msg);
        }

        protected abstract Task HandleAsync(string msg);
    }
    
    public class MyMessageHandler1 : MessageHandler
    {        
        protected override async Task HandleAsync(string msg)
        {
           // DO SOME LONG WORK        
            await _service1.DoWork();
        }       
    }  

    public class MyMessageHandler2 : MessageHandler
    {        
        protected override async Task HandleAsync(string msg)
        {
           // DO SOME WORK        
            await _service2.DoWork();
        }       
    }
```

Comment: `_messages.Reader.TryRead(out var msg);` - usually, when `TryXXX` methods return `false` then the out param is invalid. Maybe you should check that?

Comment: @Fildor, I can. But, it's not my main question :) I wanted to know if my approach is correct or I should redesign since I "steal" threads from thread pool for the duration of the whole program?

Comment: This is might be interesting implementation of producer-consumer but I see it as over-complicated mess. why not Use a concurrent blocking queue where you drop your handlers, and then just execute the handlers on the declared number of CPU threads? So, In a producer side you would have the same while loop and read messages and set a new handler for each and add to the queue. On the consumer - spin as many threads as you with and each should TryDequeue and execute. If you need to process only 1 per type - have 3 queues. You already have 3 queues.

Comment: 1) I don't see the difference then. Can you give an example? 2) As I mentioned, some handlers can take minutes to execute, others seconds. Some handlers should cancel execution of previous message (of the same type) before processing new message. Could you give an example how would you approach this?

Answer (score 2):

> I still have `Task.Run` with a loop for each message handler, meaning it will hold a whole thread from thread pool for duration of the whole program, right? So, If I have 3 message handlers, I'm holding 3 threads from thread pool, right?

I'll answer just this question. Your assumption is wrong. You are using the [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) with asynchronous delegate:

```
_task = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    while (await _messages.Reader.WaitToReadAsync())
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

The `_task` is not running on a single thread from start to finish, unless all the `await`ing inside the delegate is happening on completed awaitables, which is unlikely. Initially a [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool) thread is used for invoking the `_messages.Reader.WaitToReadAsync` method, and when the method returns that thread is released back to the `ThreadPool`. There is [no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) involved during the `await` periods, and after each `await` a different thread might run the continuation until the next `await`.

Theoretically you could have thousands of tasks similar to the `_task` running concurrently, using only a handful of threads. The ratio tasks/threads depends on how much of the work inside the loop is synchronous, and how much is asynchronous.

To understand better the `Task.Run` as a mechanism, make sure to read this article by Stephen Toub: [Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/).

Comment: 1) So, `Task.Run` (T) just makes the TaskScheduler to put the T on the queue for available thread from threadpool. Once a thread picks the T it will put it back to the queue if there is nothing to read from the `_messages.Reader` because of the `await`, right?

2) If I had replaced the `await _messages.Reader.WaitToReadAsync()` with `foreach(var msg in blockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable()) {}` then I would have "locked" the thread from thread pool for entire time of the application, right?

Comment: @theateist yes, exactly.

Comment: Just to confirm, is "yes" to both bullets in my last comment?

Comment: @theateist yes, both 1 and 2 are correct.

Comment: You wrote in your answer "I'll answer just this question.", is this because it's not clear what I want to ask? I know there is no right/wrong, but just wanted to know if my approach is not wrong :) or should I redesign like I tried to explain in bullet 3 in my post

Comment: @theateist I answered the first of the three questions because it was easy to answer. The other two questions require much more effort, starting with understanding them clearly. Even if I managed to do this, I am not at all sure that I could answer them.